# Is there any way to fake linux version info?

Tags: version, alma-linux

**Context**

I am using almalinux 9, `uname -a` gives the following output:

```
5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Nov 15 07:49:10 EST 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am trying to install a program with its own installer (which is a black box), and it gives an error message that this OS is not supported. I am aware that the cleanest solution is ask support from the manufacturer... meanwhile...

I am convinced that RHEL 8 or CentOS 8 is supported.

**Question**

Is there any way to fake my OS to el8?

Comment: You have to see which command it is using, if it gets it from `/etc/os-release` (or `/usr/lib/os-release`), this is trivial, if it gets it from elsewhere this can be really a pain

Comment: yeah, we have no idea how it decides that your operating system is "inappropriate". Chances are that **if** it cares, then it does care for a reason. What software are we talking about?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Galera Monitor

Comment: @g.pickardou stupid question, seeing this only needs network access: would installing this in an AlmaLinux 8.7 container not solve this at once?

Comment: Use `strace -f ...` to see if it calls `uname(2)` or reads a file etc, then try interposing a shim to capture that system call, using `LD_PRELOAD`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes that will be the next step, just it is not documented, what OS-es are supported, so I am going to play russian roulette with linux images. What I am not understanding in the first place, why are not they distributing it also as a Docker image, then problem solved...

Comment: @g.pickardou ah I very rarely use any stock Docker images, most of the times I need to modify them ever so slightly.

Comment: Looking at the (shell) installer it supports RHEL or RockyLinux. You picked the wrong fork: RHEL/Rocky 8 & 9 (rhel) Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (bionic), 20.04 LTS (focal), & 22.04 LTS (jammy) Debian 10 (buster), & Debian 11 (bullseye) SLES 15 (sles) (+ limited RHEL/CentOS 7 and SLES 12). Then that same installer has an option `--os-version=` to override detection... You should really check the installer. Kernel isn't checked to figure out the os in this script.

Comment: @A.B, many thx taking the time I thought that 17M download is a binary (Galera Monitor). Now I am trying to examine it and no traces of --os-version switch or any other textual data, which may indicate the supported OS-es...

Comment: I was talking about `mariadb_es_repo_setup` at https://mariadb.com/docs/server/deploy/maxscale-mariadbmon-readconnroute-mxs22-08/ . If this happens later, then sorry my comment doesn't help.